# How To store SAS dates in a macro

Tags: date, macros

I am trying to create different datasets with the names starting from a date which has data for different dates. When i am trying to run the code it is reading the date as numeric numbers and not as Dates. Here is the code

```
data dates;  
input dates mmddyy8. name : $10. ;  
format dates date9.;  
cards;  
01312015 swati  
02282015 kangan  
01232015 Gotam  
04302015 Hushiyar  
05172015  yash  
09192015 Kuldeep  
08302015 David  
05172015  yash  
11192015 Uninayal  
11192015 Uninayal  
12032015 sahil  
;  

data dates;  
set dates;  
format new date9.;  
new=intnx('month', dates, 0, 'e');  
run;  

proc sql;  
select distinct new into : new1 -: new8 from dates;  
quit;  

%put &new1.;  

%macro swati;  
%do i= 1 %to 1;  
data data_&&new&i.;  
set dates;  
if new="&&new&i." then output data_&&new&i.;  
run;  
%end;  

%mend;  
%swati;
```

**When I try running this code it gives me the error that says it is reading the dates stored in the macro as numbers. How do i make SAS read the dates as just dates only?**

Comment: did you try converting the dates in alphanumeric?e.G.: new=put(intnx('month', dates, 0, 'e'), date9.)

Comment: anothersolution would be to try "&&new&i."d or &&new&i. without " when comparing later

Comment: Hi @kl78..It worked with the second part. Thank you so much